# Chlorophyll content in relation to the pH of the solution in which it is boiled

Tags: ph

What would be the expected trend of chlorophyll content in relation to the pH of the solution in which it is boiled? Would there be the least chlorophyll degradation in basic or neutral solutions? Logically, I thought that both extremes of pH 1 and 13 would cause chlorophyll degradation, so the ideal solution pH would be 7, neutral. However, I read that acidic solutions increase degradation due to the presence of hydrogen ions, so I thought that the higher the pH, the less degradation. What would be hypothesized?